# Segue from cell in collectionViewController that has parent navigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue

I am looking at using a collectionView for a menu within an app.  I want the menu to have a navigation controller so the user knows they're in the menu and can go forwards and back between the menu and the page selected from the menu.

However as i have created the collectionView programatically i don't seem able to use a 'show' segue as the cells are created at runtime.

Interface

[image]

Runtime

[image]

Is there a way of still utilising the navigation bar for this menu?

I was previously using a static tableview with segue from each cell to desired page.  Ive got a bunch of code tied into each named segue so am reluctant to change.

[image]

Code using segues on the old tableview

class MenuTable: UITableViewController {

```
weak var centerButtonDelegate: ManageCenterButtonDelegate?

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueTour" {
        fadeOutDelegate()
    }
```

Comment: where are you calling the segue? can we see the code for that?

Comment: i don't want to segue programatically.  they were set from the tableview cells as 'show' segues. When i had the tableView going I've had some code in the prepareForSegue function that calls a delegate function.  ill edit the question to show it.

Comment: I would recommend  you to set them programatically, they are more easy to control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the cell is selected or tapped (or however you want to detect this), create the next view controller and configure it appropriately to that cell, and call [`show`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621377-show).

Comment: excellent thank you.  I have only ever used .present programatically and IB segue for navigation controller ect.

Answer (score 1):

I  think you should perform the segue programatically if you are linking a UICollectionViewCell to a new ViewController, they are way more easy to control, might be as well that you set it wrong in the storyboard too.

In your tableView delegate method 'selectedRowAt: IndexPath' you should do a switch statement and perform the segue there. Something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.item {
    case 0:
        //perfrom segue
         performSegue("mySegue", sender: self)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: and this will maintain the navigation bar on the page we segue to?